# crear un ejecutable para window 10

Tags: c#, windows, windows-installer

He terminado uno de mis varios proyectos en `c#` la cuestión es que cuando cree el ejecutable para instalarlo en mi cliente final nunca pensé que tuviese `windows 10` de `64bits`... lo hice de la manera más sencilla e intuitiva posible con el mismo VS2015 no use una herramienta como [installshield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/products/software-installation/installshield-software-installer/) mi pregunta es:

¿que debería hacer para que funcione en `win10` de `64bit`?

pues tengo el siguiente problema cuando lo ejecuto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

detalle del problema:

```
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    Código base: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.resources
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    Código base: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    Código base: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
----------------------------------------

************** Depuración JIT **************
Para habilitar la depuración Just In Time (JIT), el archivo de configuración de esta
aplicación o equipo (machine.config) debe tener el
valor jitDebugging establecido en la sección system.windows.forms.
La aplicación también se debe compilar con la depuración
habilitada

Por ejemplo:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

Cuando esté habilitada la depuración JIT, cualquier excepción no controlada
se enviará al depurador JIT registrado en el equipo
en lugar de controlarlo mediante el cuadro de diálogo.
```

Comment: A priori, cualquier aplicación de .net debería funcionar sin problemas en windows 10. Tienes algun problema en concreto?

Comment: @Pikoh acabo de editar la pregunta con el error que me da en la pc del cliente espero pueda ayudarme

Comment: El error que pones no parece que tenga nada que ver con windows 10. Debes revisar tu método `BtnIngresar_Click`,ya que parece que estas accediendo a algun objeto que no está inicializado.

Comment: Buen día, entiendo. Cambiare el método, el funciona pero ahí que descartar todo, muchas gracias

Comment: Se me ocurre que quizás falte por instalar alguna dll en el windows 10, o la versión del .net no sea la misma en los dos equipos.

Answer (score 3):

Yo solucione ese problema instalando Visual Studio en el Windows 10 y lo compilé desde ahí.

Pero según el ScreenShot que publicas, dice que la excepción es de tipo NullReferenceException y ese tipo de excepciones ocurren cuando no estas intentando acceder a un objeto que no se ha inicializado.

Te recomiendo depurar la aplicación el en Windows 10 así tendrás mas precisión a la hora de encontrar el error.

Comment: Buenas noches migo lo que pude hacer es bajarme el sdk de win10 y me dio otra excepción Entonces probé en otra maquina con win7 y quite del código el catch { ex } y me dio error 40 que específico en otra pregunta del foro: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38556/error-40-sql-server estoy desde el cel disculpa que no coloque un mejor formato @MichaelTraña

Comment: Buenas tardes amigo, respondí a tu publicación en el vínculo que agregaste en el comentario. Espero que mi respuesta te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Nunca he tenido ese problema en especifico pero puedes recopilar tu proyecto, te vas a propiedades del proyecto -> Compilar -> Destino de plataforma trae 3 opciones "any CPU", "x86" y "x64" por default esta any (quiero pensar que es cualquier procesador) pero ya sabes que x86 se refiere a 32 bits.
en lo personal no creo que el error por eso.

Comment: Buen día @blackErizo ya lo compile de las 3 manera y nada pero es un intel x64