# error 40 sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

buenas tardes, espero puedan ayudarme. me acabo de cambiar de maquina por fallas técnicas en la otra y me dice esto en mi proyecto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estuve buscando sobre el error 40 pero por lo general el management Stdio es el que no funciona y a mi si:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo unico que veo es que en los servicios este me da error al iniciar no se si tenga que ver pero ya no se que hacer

[image]

en mi otra pc:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero me ayuden

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Agents es un servicio de Microsoft que te permite automatizar ciertas tareas (o al menos ese es el uso que yo le doy) para poder usar tu instancia SQL Server ese servicio no es necesario si te fijas tu instancia (SQLEXPRESS) está automática y corre a la perfección.

Respecto a tu problema, el SQL Server Management Studio funciona por que has ingresado los datos correctamente. Según el ScreenShots que publicastes el error que tienes es que no has ingresado el nombre de tu instancia SQL Sever correctamente. Por lo visto tu nombre de servidor es EDUARD-PC\SQLEXPRESS así que eso mismo debes ingresar en el Visual Studio. En Visual Studio veo que dices que tu instancia es "." y por eso te manda ese error. Intenta cambiar donde dice **Nombre del Servidor** y escribe **EDUARD-PC\SQLEXPRESS**

---

Estuve haciendo pruebas en mi computador sobre conectar Visual Studio 2015 con mi Instancia Local de SQL Server 2014 usando la forma que tu usas (es decir "." para conexión localmente) y ni en SQL Server ni en Visual Studio me ha permitido conectarme.

SQL Server 2014
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Visual Studio 2015
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te recomendaria que pongas EDUARD-PC\SQLEXPRESS en el VS 2015 para conectarte. Solo has el intento quizas y te funciona.

Comment: buen día amigo pero el `.` segun `VS2015` es el nombre en local de tu base de datos es lo mismo que escriba `(local)` o `EDUARD-PC` y de ninguna manera se conectò a ella @MichaelTraña

Comment: @GilbertoAsuaje Michael. Eviten usar saludos, gratificaciones, etc, en las publicaciones. Damos por sentado que todos los usuarios compartimos las normas de saludo, gratitud, etc, así que las publicaciones se deben centrar principalmente en el corazón del contenido que es la respuesta al problema.

Comment: @Michael acabo de subir una captura de mi otra PC y ahí con el punto si se conecta, por eso lo uso así, también trate de cambiar el nombre pero no, no se conecto y si así fuese no puedo usar ese nombre en el conf. ya que el cliente final no va a tener ese mismo nombre. Ahora me surge lo siguiente. Ya tengo esta pc y puedo seguir trabajando aquí pero si el error esta en el `punto` como lo guardo, lo compilo o lo distribuyo para la pc de mi  N cliente??

Comment: @GilbertoAsuaje ya intentastes habilitar las Canalizaciones con nombre o Named Pipes en el SQL Server Configuration Manager...

Comment: No , como lo hago?

Comment: Revisa este tutorial para hacerlo es muy fácil en la configuración de tu sql server https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkenablenamedpipesandtcpipconnections.htm